# Cannot create MicroStation .net project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, microstation

I am trying to create plugin for MicroStation, using .net framework following this tutorial :
https://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/w/wiki/52303/introduction-and-prerequisite

I have those installed on my PC (windows 10 x64):

[image]
[image]

However when I try to create a new project in visual studio, there is no option relative to Bentley or Microstation.

Is there anything missing in my configuration ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself :
In addition to what is listed in the tutorial, you need to install the extension "VS 2019 Tools for MicroStation CONNECT Edition", which can be found in the extension market inside VS.